# Subscribe 2 admin users to an app in Quickbooks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We have developed an application which is integrated with quickbooks.
I have two admin users on my quickbooks account and i m trying to login with both the admins but after the first admin is being logged in then it doesnot let me logged in with another admin.

In the developer account in my app.i have disconnected all the connected connections.but it always makes only one connection and shows : "You are using 1 out of your 10 connections".After having that one connection when i try to login with another admin it gives me the below error message.

Error Code: invalid_database
Message: The application has already been subscribed to by another user for this company

Can anybody please help me how to subscribe two admin user to my app OR i can only login with a single admin user ?

Answer (score 1):

In practice you can only have one connection or perhaps more accurately one set of valid OAuth tokens per company. Get and store the OAuth tokens for a particular company. Use those OAuth tokens for all users within a company.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but how do i subscribe more than one user to my app ? So that i can use the app oauth values for multiple users.I am using the quickbooks online plus version and I have given rights to 3 user into my quickbooks online plus account but from the project that we developed , it only lets me login with a single user.

Comment: All users for an account must share the single set of OAuth tokens. Again, you cannot have multiple users per account authenticate through the API. Only one of the account users can authenticate at a time. Within the your client application have all of the users share that authentication.

Comment: Can anyone else please elaborate on the same topic that how would i login with a master admin and a company admin at the same time to quickbooks ?

Comment: It is not possible for 2 admins to login at the same time unless the oauth tokens have been saved and used again for the second user. It's a bit of a hack I would say.

Comment: Minimul and @nimishashrivastava for your consult but it did not work.I have tried to login with the second user with the oauth token values of previously saved logined user and all i understand the game depends on authorizeURL. when i tried to login with the authorizedURL of the previous saved user it gives me an "internal error" message and when i tried to login with the new authorizedURL it gives me the same error message "invalid database".So in both the cases i am not able to login with the second user.            Any comments... Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sorry, but we both tried to explain this the best we can.

Comment: @Minimul: thanks for the explaination but the thing i am saying is i implemented what you said and it is not working so do you have any other idea over this..

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one user signed up for a connection at a time. If you need to have more than one person access the company file, you need to handle the user authentication and data access in your app for that company.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but does user authentication means that i have to store my oauth tokens of first time login user for all users or it means something different ?